# Something I'm trying to do in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

I am scraping a lot of data from sites and have crafted table structure which makes sense to me.

Now, I'm trying to pull that data in sets, based on relationships.
So i've got a table full of coin_a for coin_b trades.

```
OPEN_TRADES: coin_id_a coin_id_b exchange_id action_type price amount time
```

What I'd like to do, is join data from the coins table with id_a and id_b.

```
COINS: id name short_name
```

I started off with this:

```
SELECT `op`.`coin_id_a`, `op`.`coin_id_b`, `op`.`exchange_id`,
    `op`.`action_type`, `op`.`price`, `op`.`amount`, `op`.`time`,
    `c`.`name` , `c`.`short_name`
    FROM `open_trades` as `op`
        LEFT JOIN `coins` as `c`
            ON `op`.`coin_id_a`=`c`.`id`
```

This works exactly as I expected it to. But it only solves half the data I want.
I'd like to perform this join again for coin_id_b.

I just don't have the *proper* tool for doing this in MySQL under my belt. And quite frankly that bugs me :D

I know I can do this in php, in fact I was doing exactly this. The issue is its not efficient in php. 
I know that my database will do this faster. Especially because my trades table is running in memory.

The result schema I'm looking to create looks like this:

```
coin_id_a coin_id_b exchange_id action_type price amount time id_a name_a
short_name_a id_b name_b short_name_b
```

---

What is the proper way to join 2 separate rows from the same table onto two separate fields in another table in mysql?

Comment: Do you mean something like `LEFT JOIN coins as c
            ON op.coin_id_a=c.id OR op.coin_id_b=c.id`?

Comment: No because I need the coin data, for **both** coin_id_a and coin_id_b.

Comment: Do you mean a [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join)?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be like that. I want to copy coin data where coin_id_a = coin.id, THEN (not and) copy coin data where coin_id_b = coin.id. If the coins table was two tables, I know I could do this with a double left join.

Comment: You can still do a double left join. Start with `SELECT op.*, coin_a.*, coin_b.* FROM open_trades AS op LEFT JOIN coins AS coin_a ON op.coin_id_a = coin_a.id LEFT JOIN coins AS coin_b ON op.coin_id_b = coin_b.id`. But remember to give more meaningful and *distinct* aliases to the resulting columns.

Comment: Your absolutely right DCoder. I was thinking inside of a box.
If I give the table i'm joining **from** two separate aliases I can use it twice. A hundred times. Haha. Lightbulb comes on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the proper way to join 2 separate rows from the same table onto two separate fields in another table in mysql?

Give that table two different aliases, and provide unique aliases for the columns being selected.

Given your schema, it might look like this:

```
SELECT
      op.coin_id_a, op.coin_id_b, op.exchange_id,
      op.action_type, op.price, op.amount, op.time,
      coin_a.id AS id_a, coin_a.name AS name_a, coin_a.short_name AS short_name_a,
      coin_b.id AS id_b, coin_b.name AS name_b, coin_b.short_name AS short_name_b
FROM open_trades AS op
LEFT JOIN coins AS coin_a
 ON op.coin_id_a = coin_a.id
LEFT JOIN coins AS coin_b
 ON op.coin_id_b = coin_b.id
```

---

A remark made in the comments:

> If I give the table i'm joining from two separate aliases I can use it twice. **A hundred times.**

I realise this was said in jest, but here's a trivia fact nonetheless: in MySQL, you cannot have a hundred joins in one query, there's a built-in [limit of **61** table in a single query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/joins-limits.html).

Comment: Thanks was waiting for ya to post an answer. 
That is quite quite funny. 61. I'll remember that.